# Doing spatial analysis on ArcGIS service containing more than 100,000 records?

Tags: arcgis-portal, limitations

I was using the CadastreParcels layer to do spatial analysis in ArcGIS, and got below the error, according to Esri’s help, it says only layers contain fewer than 100,000 features could do analysis, there are more in it.

[image]

https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/use/use-analysis-tools.htm

Is there any other way to do spatial analysis on big service layer?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Thank you for having taken the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Would you be able to include the error message that you are receiving as formatted text rather than as a picture, please?

Answer (score 0):

Technically the administrator of the GIS server would need to redeploy the service using Portal for ArcGIS and configure the parcels as a "hosted service" which allows ArcGIS Server to manage the storage of the data sets and and more efficiently perform large analysis operations.  You would need to access the service through the Portal  for ArcGIS.

But you would need to influence the administrator to do so which is a big ask.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and Yes, as it's not our service, it's a published service by a government agency, so very difficult to convince them to do so.